# posting an empty array is insecure? why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've noticed in rails logs if there's ever a post of an empty array it says:

```
**attribute** was set to nil, because it was one of [], [null] or [null, null, ...]. Go to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#unsafe-query-generation for more information.
```

When reading the article found at that url and section, they give the example of:

> Due to the way Active Record interprets parameters in combination with
>   the way that Rack parses query parameters it was possible to issue
>   unexpected database queries with IS NULL where clauses. As a response
>   to that security issue (CVE-2012-2660, CVE-2012-2694 and
>   CVE-2013-0155) deep_munge method was introduced as a solution to keep
>   Rails secure by default.
>
> Example of vulnerable code that could be used by attacker, if
>   deep_munge wasn't performed is:

```
unless params[:token].nil?
  user = User.find_by_token(params[:token])
  user.reset_password!
end
```

Ok-- for their example, assume params[:token] = []

So:

```
User.find_by_token([])
```

which will trigger:

```
User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE 1=0 LIMIT 1
```

which returns no user...  So next:

```
user.reset_password!
```

which will be the same as:

```
nil.reset_password!
```

...

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `reset_password!' for nil:NilClass
```

...

So where is this security vulnerability in this example???

Answer (score 1):

In the example vulnerability the author performed a check for a nil token: `unless params[:token].nil?` and then called `User.find_by_token` assuming that they had guarded against a nil case.

Unfortunately for them, if `params[:token]` was empty rather than `nil` the `find_by_token` would still execute returning the first `User` with a nil `token`. (The query would be something like `SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE token IS NULL LIMIT 1`. I'm not sure where you got `WHERE 1=0` from.)

Comment: I got that from putting it in the console...  User.where(:token => []).to_sql  => "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE 1=0"  ... and User.find_by_token([]) => User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE 1=0 LIMIT 1  ...  Neither of these statements will actually ever return a user, so I think the example in the rails guide is bogus.

Comment: However, User.find_by_token([nil]) would do:  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."token" IS NULL LIMIT 1, so I get that.. I just don't get the empty array case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are oodles of examples, but one might be:

Assume `params[:foo]` is `[null, null,...]` then you could have code like this:

```
params.each do |foo|
  User.where(foo: foo)…
end
```

Which would result in some `SELECT * FROM users where foo IS NULL` which might not be what you want.

I haven't looked but I imagine there are some in-depth blog posts on the whys...